# Yii2 Rest api не могу получить POST данные

Tags: php, yii2, post, rest

Вообщем отправляю данные в api таким образом:

```
axios.post(environment.url + '/api/v1/users/registration', payload, { headers }).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Но при попытке получить из в yii2, таким образом:

```
$user['bodyParams'] = Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams();
```

Я получаю пустой массив, но есть я делаю вот так:

```
$user['raw'] = Yii::$app->request->getRawBody();
```

То я могу полчить данные как строку, но это мне не подходит.

Как мне получить данные нормально через POST??

Comment: что у вас в `payload` лежит?

Comment: @ArchDemon Вот это `{username: "", email: "user@admin.com", password_hash: "123456"}`
Насколько я понял посмотрев debug yii2, я похоже неправильно отправляю POST

Comment: Поэтому и не работает. У вас лежит json, а нужно `FormData()`

Comment: @ArchDemon т.е. мне придётся каждый раз переформатировать данные в FormData()... как-то это не особо практично.

Comment: Я не знаток Yii2, но столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой в самописном фреймворке. Может быть в нём и можно трансформировать данные из json автоматом. Может вы в запросе в заголовках не указываете тип передаваемых данных (application/json). Может нужно какой-то компонент подключать в сам yii2.

Comment: @ArchDemon В том то и дело, что указывается и данные, что приходят должны преобразовывать, это всё в конфиге прописано, но почему-то это не происходит.
Вот `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8` передаётся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё я нашел в чём проблема, у меня api на которое я отправляю данные находятся в модуле, и почему-то надстройка для модуля не хотела срабатывать, после я перенёс парсер в основной код так:

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'request' => [
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'd49ipDXNBI0afLqoza9dkfYng6bPycKB',
        'parsers' => [
            'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser'
        ],
    ],
    ...
]
```

И внезапно всё начало работать